# Asp.Net MVC ValidationSummary HTML error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've been asked to include a link in an error message when the Email address for a registration is already in use.

The validation for this property is done with a IValidatableObject.Validate function on the model. My validate function looks like so...

```
Public Overridable Function Validate(validationContext As ValidationContext) As IEnumerable(Of ValidationResult) Implements IValidatableObject.Validate
    Dim results = New List(Of ValidationResult)()

    ....

    If Not EmailAvailable(Email) Then
        results.Add(New ValidationResult("The email address is not available. <a href=""/forgot_password"">Forgot Password?</a>", {"Email"}))
    End If
    Return results
End Function
```

In my views, I'm using a custom "MyValidationSummary" extension function to format the errors nicely.

The extension function does this...

```
....

Dim ul = New TagBuilder("ul")
For Each key In helper.ViewData.ModelState.Keys
    For Each e In helper.ViewData.ModelState(key).Errors
        Dim li = New TagBuilder("li") With {
            .InnerHtml = helper.Encode(e.ErrorMessage)
        }
        ul.InnerHtml += li.ToString()
    Next
 Next
 container.InnerHtml += ul.ToString()
 Return New MvcHtmlString(container.ToString())
```

I know I could just remove helper.Encode, and just output the message as raw html, but this feels a bit hacky.

I'm trying to find a nice way to be able to selectively include html in the messages, while still retaining the default behaviour of encoding plain text messages.

What I thought of doing, is create a custom ValidationResult class, which optionally would include a HTMLString property, so that I can, if I choose, include HTML in the messages.

I can do this, but I don't know if there is any way to get at this custom ValidationResult from MyValidationSummary.

update:
For the time being, I've just added a placeholder tag into the error message, which I then substitute with the actual link in my MyValidationSummary extension method. It's very hacky, but it will work until I've found a better way to do it.

Comment: do you forget model binding ?

Comment: @Prageethgodage Sorry I don't follow? I'm doing model binding, but I'm not sure how that's related.

Comment: why you generating html by code I feel like it very expensive work can't you seperate UI logic to handle UI itself and backed work to do non complex work only business logic.

Comment: I'm open to better ways to do what I need to do. Basically I just need a nice way to be able to check if an email address is available, and if not, to display an error message including a link to a "forgot password" controller action.

Comment: Also in the example above, I've just hard-coded the link. In practice I'd use an extension to get the correct path for the controller and action.

Comment: @Prageethgodage, OP is writing a `HtmlHelper` method!

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have clarified this. The ValidationSummary is a helper method to format the messages as Bootstrap notifications with a close button etc. As a general rule I avoid generating HTML tags in my code, but it made sense for the error summary.